# UI style issue for a freestyle project

Tags: jenkins

in my jenkins version v2.412, when I created a job with freestyle, the configure UI style for freestyle project is not working correctly since it is almost samilar with pipeline project. could you please let me know how to fix it?

the configure UI style should be different with pipeline project.

Comment: those menu list only display at the left of config window but not at the up location, not sure why and how to fix it?